# Rendering in a map function lead to a JsLint error as Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression?

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

I have created a react application. There it is giving me an error of

```
 Line 13:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

This is my code which is causing the error.

```
renderList = movies => {
    if (movies) {
      return movies.map((movie, index) => {
        <div>Hi</div>;
      });
    }
  };
```

Can someone help me to modify this code part to get rid of this error?. Because every question regarding this error says only to remove the JsHint expression. I want to do it without disabling the JsHint expression. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with below solution?

Comment: @HemadriDasari yeah It works.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map function missing return keyword and you also need to set unique key to div element which is missing in your code

Change

```
  return movies.map((movie, index) => {
    <div>Hi</div>;
  });
```

To

With curly brackets and return

```
 return movies.map((movie, index) => {
    return <div key={"Key-"+index}>Hi</div>;
  });
```

Or

Without curly brackets and without return

```
 return movies.map((movie, index) => <div key={"Key-"+index}>Hi</div>);
```

Anyone of the above change would fix the error